# Delete/Ignore first two rows of .dat when importing pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code in which I am trying to load a df splitting the data by commas

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\jmwil\Downloads\data.dat',
            header=None, sep=',', engine='python')
```

However it produces the following error `pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 9 fields in line 3, saw 22` Its because the data is kinda like this(below) Essentially the first two rows in the worksheet dont belong to the table. I would like to find a solution that doesn't require me going into the files and deleting the two rows above the data table I am actually interested in just because there are thousands. How do I either load without the first two rows or make python delete the first two rows of the .dat file? I cant give the exact data out but I have tried to replicate the issue below.

```
xyz 2010, 209, 145
xyz 2010, 209, 145
date, amount, type, location, count, etc...., 22nd column
```

Input

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
A,B,C,D,E,F,H
1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2,2
3,3,3,3,3,3,3
```

Desired output in a df

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,H
1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2,2
3,3,3,3,3,3,3
```

Comment: pass `skiprows=2` to `pd.read_csv`

Comment: Thanks so much Quang

Answer (score 0):

Even though @Quang Hong recommended skiprows=2, I wanted to still post this answer since I think it is a bit more useful. Pandas.read_csv has the option error_bad_lines, which basically skips every single line which causes an error. Use it like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\jmwil\Downloads\data.dat',
        header=None, sep=',', engine='python', error_bad_lines=False)
```

This works with .csv files, so I guess it should also work with .dat files(correct me if I'm wrong)